# Altium Gerber File Copper Breaks

Tags: ground, altium, gerber

I'm getting some really weird effects on my Gerber File outputs from Altium

Altium 18.1.9, using OutJob Files, here are my settings 
[image: Gerber File Settings]

My layers look completely normal with a copper pour for the ground plane like shown here

[image: normal ground]

However, when I export Gerber files, I get these bizarre lines through everything that seem like they would cause everything to be connected to ground, 
[image: not good]

I have no idea what is causing this, have any of you seen this before or have any suggestions for things to try? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try exporting the layer as PDF, or use some different gerber viewers to verify? Do all give the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ADDING three mechanical layers to each copper plot. Don't do that.

Welcome, and thanks for the well-written question with **all** the information provided up front. +1

Comment: @Katie I think they originally provided that "feature" so you could add outlines etc. to the copper layer, but nowadays we usually provide the outlines as a separate Gerber (helping to ensure the board house doesn't forget to remove it and give you copper slivers around the outside) so I don't think it should ever be used (or rarely at best).